# ios-papulate tableview with array of indexpaths of another array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, nsindexpath

i have two `UITableView` in my app (RootTableView and FavoritesTableView).
in first table i have button in `UITableViewCell` for add or remove cell to favorites array 
(i have main array thats fill RootTableView so favorites array in array of `indexpath` of favorite row in main array)

i implementation button function correctly.when i press button `indexpath` for selected row add to an favorites array and when i press again button `indexpath` for selected row remove from the favorites array.

my problem is how can use this favorites array for populate my FavoritesTableView?how can use `indexpath` to show main array?
(i use singlton to share favarray so sharing is not my issue)

Comment: can you show me the UI that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

in mainpage 
on clicking on favorite

```
[favorites_array addObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

on clicking on unfavorite

```
if([favorites_array containsObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]) {
[favorites_array removeObject:[mainArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
[mainArrayTable reloadData];
```

You can pass favorites_array into favoritespage

in favoritespage on clicking on unfavorite

```
[favorites_array removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[favoritesArrayTable reloadData];
```

Comment: thanks vaibby.this  solve my problem;but when i terminate app and run it's again nothing saved?what can i do?